# Get value from simple JSON data doesn't work?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON data in a database field:

```
{
 "order_id":"123456789",
 "country_id":"SE",
 "method_title":"Checkout",
 "payment_method":"INVOICE",
 "queue_id":"123456789"
 }
```

I have this function to get the data:

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource){
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            ...
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

How do I get the value from `payment_method`?

In the example data above, it should be `INVOICE`.

### ***Update 1***

`$dataSource['data']['items']` is giving me exactly this (as `$item`):

```
{
"order_id":"123456789",
"country_id":"SE",
"method_title":"Checkout",
"payment_method":"INVOICE",
"queue_id":"123456789"
}
```

If I use `json_decode` on `$item` or on `$dataSource['data']['items']` i receive the following error:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.
```

Hope this answers your questions better.

### ***Update 2***

`gettype($item)` output is: `"array"`

`json_decode(strval($item), true)` output is: *Notice: Array to string conversion...*

### ***Update 3***

If I try `print_r` on `$item` output shows:

```
Array (
...
[additional_information] => {"order_id":123456789,
                             "country_id":"SE",
                             "method_title":" Checkout",
                             "payment_method":"INVOICE",
                             "queue_id":"123456789"
                             }
...
)
```

Comment: Well for a start, you will need to reference something with the name `payment_method`

Comment: Show us code from the `json_decode()` so we know 1) that you did decode it 2) what you called things. 3) that you decoded it to an array

Comment: If you are doing this `isset($dataSource['data']['items'])` one has to assume that this data is a little more complex than you are showing to us. PLease dont protect us from the truth, **we can take it** and you may even get a more useful answer

Comment: So `$dataSource['data']['items']` is supposed to be the element that contains this JSON? Is it actually _still_ JSON, or do you have it decoded at this point already?

Comment: Updated the question with some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. Good clarification.

The `$dataSource['data']['items']`, needs to be a string in order to run `json_decode();`.

Try this: `json_decode(strval($item), true);`.

Otherwise please print out `gettype($item)` and update the question with the response you get.

Comment: Updated the question with some more information. The code comes from an simple extension in Magento 2.4. I'm not sure what code to show. But the data is fetched with a simple SQL query without any encoding or similar. So I'll guess it's just clear text.

Comment: Your code showed the same data as earlier, no changes.

Comment: @Alldo The code I previously posted contained one alteration: the inclusion of `json_decode()`. But try my edited solution and get back to me with the results.

Comment: @Alldo What datatype is the column in the database? Does `$item['payment_method']` work?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the input of `json_decode()` needs to be a string, but $item seems to be an array. Arrays in PHP use 'key => value' as the valid syntax. If you `echo $item;` or `print_r($item);`, what output do you get?

Comment: I understand, thank your for your help so far, adding update number 3

Comment: @Alldo Okay, now I think I got it. You stated before that $item contains exactly the JSON-string. But it actually contains an array containing the JSON-string. Try this to get the `payment_method`: `$payment_method = json_decode($item['additional_information'], true);`. Should do the trick.